# Is there a way I can share a function that I have attached to my scope between controllers?

Tags: angularjs

I have a function that I will attach to my scope like this. It's attached to the scope as I use this function in my HTML pages Presently I am doing this in more than one controller. Note that my controllers are all top level controllers so I cannot really put this in a higher up controller and have it inherited.

```
    $scope.isNotString = function (str) {
        return (typeof str !== "string");
    }
```

I asked how I could share this functionality and was given the following

**example:**

```
app.service('myService',function(){
   this.sharedFunction = function() {
      //do some stuff
   };
});

myCntrl1($scope,myService) {
   $scope.doSomething = function() {
      myService.sharedFunction();
   }
}

myCntrl2($scope,myService) {
   $scope.doSomething = function() {
      myService.sharedFunction();
   }
}
```

Is there a way that I could more directly share it by passing
in `$scope` to the service and in that way eliminating the need for:

```
$scope.doSomething = function() {
  myService.sharedFunction();
}
```

In each controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the function to the parent (root) scope, but using a service is the preferred way of sharing code between controllers.

You could call `myService.init($scope)` in the controller and that function could append properties to the scope but more likely you would want to use a parent controller from which you inherit.

Answer (score 1):

You either declare a shared function in a top level "controller" or in a "service" like you mentioned in your example. There's no other better way so far.

You can assign the scope to a global variable, that will expose that scope globally, but will behave the same way like "service", except you don't have to inject it like service, rather can call by globalVar.dosomething().